# How can I use Synopsys VCS for dynamic voltage scaling in a micro processor?

Tags: riscv, synopsys-vcs

I'm trying to simulate a RISCV based processor on Synopsys VCS with RTL design (verilog). I would like to change the voltage dynamically while the simulation is running. Is there any tool in Synopsys that can be used for performing dynamic voltage scaling in a microprocessor. Or is it possible to do so in testbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of analog values such as voltage in verilog or VHDL.  Just digital signals and simple timing.
Analog  simulations are done in other languages like SPICE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we change analog values after synthesis and getting gate level netlist?

Comment: This is out of my expertise, so I'm not sure. It may be possible to export from a gate level netlist to spice netlist, but you would need to know a bunch of values I'm not sure where you would get.  Transistor model parameters, trace capacitances and resistances, etc, etc.  Do you have access to these values? I also have not heard of analog simulations of entire processors, I'd imagine it would be incredibly slow.  Maybe simulate one module at a time.